# How to get latest cmake version from CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, cmake, centos6, centos6.5

Is there a good way to install latest cmake version from CentOS 6.5?

I'm doing `yum install cmake` but it's giving me 2.6.4 from base repo which I don't want.

I tried installing `cmake28` but the problem is that when I try to do `./configure` it throws an error saying cmake is not available.

Answer (score 11):

`rpm -Uv ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/Application:/Geo/CentOS_6/x86_64/cmake-3.0.0-143.1.x86_64.rpm`
Hope this helps to somebody. If you have any problems with it let me know. Have fun.

Comment: Elaborate your answer please.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an ancient question, but I got here by google searching and wanted to share what I knew so far.

when you `sudo yum install cmake28`, you get a /usr/bin/cmake28 binary on your machine.  You can setup a symlink to make your configure script work via the following:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cmake28 /usr/bin/cmake`

Not sure why the cmake28 package doesn't do this for you.

Comment: for me, this is the correct answer, but, in My system is the cmake3, so I make the same `# ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake`. Another apart is that before I can create the Link I needed to remove the old cmake, but instead of removing I renamed it to cmake_old

Answer (score 1):

Well, after looking at the tutorial CMake gives on their website, it says [download this](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) and after that you have too type "./bootstrap" followed by "make" and "make install".

If you get any errors type "sudo" in front of all the said commands. If that doesn't work, your best bet would be too login to the root account by typing "su" and the root password following that.

If you already have cmake installed you should either follow the steps cmake offers [on their website](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/install.html) or try the command "sudo yum remove cmake".

Comment: I'm getting `bash: cmake: command not found` after following the steps `./bootstrap` `make` `make install`

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper Make sure you have the GNU C++ compiler installed on your machine. You can install it with the command written INSIDE the parenthesis, not the parenthesis itself, (sudo yum group install "Development Tools")